# Why is GSC saying https://www.example.co.uk/index.html is Duplicate without user-selected canonical but https://www.example.co.uk is not?

Tags: google-search-console

I recently (4 weeks or so ago) launched a food recipe website and have been getting Google to index the pages by submitting an updated sitemap and requesting it to index specific pages with some success. However, recently GSC has decided that the homepage - `index.html` is a duplicate of another, which is very strange, because the home page is far different from any other page on the site. The only similarity to other pages are two photo's at the bottom of the page that point to the respective recipes.

The thing that is baffling me most is that the website URL `https://www.example.co.uk/` is of course `https://www.example.co.uk/index.html`

So, could someone please explain why Google Search console is saying that `https://www.example.co.uk/index.html` is:

> Duplicate without user-selected canonical

while at the same time `https://www.example.co.uk/` is indexed correctly

This is the first website that I have asked Google to index, so my knowledge on GSC is not so great. Doesn't GSC know that `https://www.example.co.uk/` is `https://www.example.co.uk/index.html`? It seams a little discombobulating to me!

One thing I  have noticed is that `https://www.example.co.uk/.index.html` is not specifically named in the site map:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.co.uk</loc>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
        <lastmod>2023-12-03</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.co.uk/beef-curry-with-green-beans.html</loc>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
        <lastmod>2023-12-03</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.co.uk/basmati-rice.html</loc>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
        <lastmod>2023-12-01</lastmod>
    </url>
    ...
</urlset>
```

PS: I'm using the 'Sitemap Generator by Nils Soderman' extension within VS Code to generate the site map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a duplicate URL.  `/index.html` is the exact same content as `/`.  Google doesn't want to index both, so it detects that they have the same content and chooses one.

Google says "without user selected canonical" because you are not using canonical link tags in the `<head>` section:
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.co.uk/">` that would unambiguously tell Google which one you prefer as your canonical URL.

There are two reasons that Google is selecting the one without `index.html` to index:

- You list the one without  in your sitemap.  Google uses your sitemap as a canonicalization signal when you don't use tags.
- `index.html` is supposed to be hidden.  Ideally users and search engines are never supposed to know it exists.

If you added canonical tags to your site.  Google would change the messaging to say that it detected the duplicate  URL and chose the user-selected canonical.

To that last point, you should check your pages and make sure that you aren't linking to `index.html` anywhere on your site.  You should always link to your home page with links that don't have it using links like:

- absolute: `<a href="https://www.example.co.uk/">`
- root relative: `<a href="/">`
- document relative (not recommended because it will be different for different documents based on their directory depth): `<a href="./">` or `<a href="../">` or `<a href="../../">`

Comment: Ah! The navigation menu has a link to https://www.example.co.uk/.index.html whereas you are saying that it should link to https://www.example.co.uk/ if I understand you correctly. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes, your navigation menu should not use `index.html` in the link.

Comment: I was not aware of this fact. I wrote a little program that puts the nav menu together for each page & I have corrected this now, and by what you are saying, I should not request that google index the index.html page. Am I correct in that?

Comment: No, `index.html` is for behind-the-scene use.  You want to have content on the home page.  Content has to go in some file.  The convention is to use `index.html` to contain the content for the directory index.  It should never publicly appear in your URLs.